# display other data within `each` ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have an application where I'm displaying albums and users

I'm currently outputting the albums,

```rb
<main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-5">Albums</h1>
    <p class="lead">Here we show all albums and it's details</p>

    <div class="row">
      <% @albums.each do |album| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%# image_tag(@albumImage ['thumbnailUrl']) %>
          <h5 class="card-title">
            <%= album['title'] %>
          </h5>

          <p>By: <%= album['userId'] %><p>
          <%= link_to "View Album", album_path(album['id']), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= will_paginate @albums, renderer: WillPaginate::ActionView::BootstrapLinkRenderer, class: 'margin-auto' %>
</main>
```

But I want to get the user so I can display the album creators name, currently, I'm displaying the album users id

```rb
<p>By: <%= album['userId'] %><p>
```

Ideally, I would like to do something like this

```rb
<p>By: <%= album.user['name'] %><p>
```

All of the data is coming from an external API, in the controller I have

```rb
require 'will_paginate/array'

class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @albums = HTTParty.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums', :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @user = HTTParty.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
  end
end
```

Not sure how best to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm going to assume that `@user` is actually an `array` of `users`. If that's true, you might want to do:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'

class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @albums = HTTParty.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums', :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @users = HTTParty.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
  end
end
```

Then, you should be able to do:

```
<main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-5">Albums</h1>
    <p class="lead">Here we show all albums and it's details</p>

    <div class="row">
      <% @albums.each do |album| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%# image_tag(@albumImage ['thumbnailUrl']) %>
          <h5 class="card-title">
            <%= album['title'] %>
          </h5>

          <p>By: <%= @users.find{|u| u['id'] == album['userId']}.try(:[],'name') || 'not available' %><p>
          <%= link_to "View Album", album_path(album['id']), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= will_paginate @albums, renderer: WillPaginate::ActionView::BootstrapLinkRenderer, class: 'margin-auto' %>
</main>
```

This:

```
@users.find{|u| u['id'] == album['userId']}
```

...will iterate the `@users` array and find the `user` that has the `id` that matches `album['userId']`.

This:

```
.try(:[],'name')
```

...will attempt to get the `name` attribute from the found `user` but will not throw and error if a `user` was not found.

And this:

```
|| 'not available'
```

...will display 'not available' if the `user` didn't have a `name` or if a `user` wasn't found.